# HTML href fails to call any div tags while using angular js ng-controller

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Well I came across with a conflict while I'm using `HTML`  using angular js ng-controller so has an error result in URL it shows a slash, in addition, like 
localhost:8080/test/#/m1 such has can someone guide me how to handle this error

```html
 <style>
        a{  }
        .target {  }
        .target > div { display:none; }
        .target > div:target{ display:block; }
 </style>
<div>
     <a href="#m1">fea1</a>
     <a href="#m2">fea1</a>
    <div class="target" ng-controller="createUpdateReadDeleteCtrl">
        <div id="m1">content m 1</div>
       <div id="m2">content m 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your ``ng-controller``?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="/m1"> fea1 </a>
<a href="/m2"> fea1 </a>
```